# QGIS 3.18 difference doesn't work with points as the input layer

Tags: qgis, differences

I am trying to run the difference algorithm with points as the input layer and a polygon as the overlay layer.  I've tried many different point layers and polygon layers and it keeps giving me the error

> GEOS geoprocessing error: difference failed.

It does work with a polygon input layer and a point overlay layer as well as polygons as both input and overlay layers.

This algorithm worked a year ago in a model I built but now it seems to have changed.

*Edit*  I switched to 'extract by location' - disjoint.   I am curious why the difference algorithm has changed. The mysteries of QGIS...

Comment: See here for possible solutions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/408820/88814

Comment: @Babel thats for a points layer as input AND overlay.  I have a polygon as an overlay

Comment: No problem - the principles should work as well in this context.

Comment: @Babel it's not the principles I'm having issue with.  It's just not working.

Comment: If you buffer the points, it does not work? You're trying to delete those points that are within a polygon - right? Would that be a solution: select points within polygon, then delete them?

Comment: Odd if it worked before. I can find similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818679/geopandas-difference-methode-between-polygon-and-points, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263664/points-and-polygons-difference-issue-qgis. Removing something from the interior of a polygon should create a hole, but point has no area so the hole would also have a zero area.

Comment: @Babel, I can do a workaround no problem.  I'm wondering if anybody is having the same issue.  If this is a bug it should be fixed.

Comment: Polygon minus point  cannot work - conceptually: or how should the result look like? This is not a QGIS problem. Only point minus point can work.

Comment: Maybe it can help you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/305193/99589

Comment: @Taras : one of the famous, all time top answers here on GIS SE!

Comment: I think you are overestimating it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "GEOS geoprocessing error: difference failed" issue with the "Difference" processing algorithm is now fixed in the developer version QGIS 3.27.0-Master starting from the [5a6b76a](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/5a6b76abaffec7acce26e0b412759383c5732832) commit, and will be fixed in the stable versions starting from QGIS 3.26.1 and from QGIS LTR 3.22.10.

See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/49300.